# How to test redux saga using jest?

Tags: testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I'm noob at front-end dev, but try to write tests for project.
Also, I'm using redux-saga and jest for testing
btw, I have saga:

```
export function* setAuthorizeCode(action) {
  try {
    let response = yield call(Api.token.getToken, action.payload.authorizeCode);

    yield put(appActions.setAccessToken(response.data.access_token));
    yield put(appActions.setIdToken(response.data.id_token));

    const accessToken = yield select((state) => appSelectors.getAccessToken(state.app));
    const idToken = yield select((state) => appSelectors.getIdToken(state.app));

    response = yield call(Api.user.getUser, accessToken, idToken);
    yield put(appActions.setUser(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
} 

function* setAuhtorizeCodeFlow () {
  yield takeLatest(appActions.SET_AUTHORIZE_CODE, setAuthorizeCode);
}

export default function* authentication() {
  yield all([
    setAuhtorizeCodeFlow()
  ]);
}
```

And I'm write this test for this:

```
test('TESTING SAGAS', function(t)  {
  const gen = setAuthorizeCode()
  let next = gen.next(appActions.setAuthorizeCode())
  t.deepEqual(next.value, call(Api.token.getToken), 'must yield api.getToken')

  next = gen.next(accessToken)
  t.deepEqual(next.value, put(appActions.setAccessToken(accessToken)), 'must yield action appActions.setAccessToken')

  next = gen.next(idToken)
  t.deepEqual(next.value, put(appActions.setIdToken(idToken)), 'must yield action appActions.setIdToken')

  next = gen.next()
  t.deepEqual(next.value, select(accessToken), 'must select accessToken')

  next = gen.next()
  t.deepEqual(next.value, select(idToken), 'must select idToken')

  next = gen.next(Api.user.getUser())
  t.deepEqual(next.value, call(Api.user.getUser), 'must yield api.getUser')

  next = gen.next(setUser)
  t.deepEqual(next.value, put(appActions.setUser(setUser)), 'must yield appActions.setUser')

  t.end()
})
```

I really don't know what is wrong.
But it's doesn't work, please I need some help, what am I doing wrong?

There is errors:

```
operator: deepEqual 
expected: |- { '@@redux-saga/IO': true, CALL: { context: null, fn: 
[Function: getToken], args: [] } } 
actual: |- undefined
```

And other 2 are the same.

Comment: Could you please explain _in what way_ it doesn't work?

Comment: @Roland Weber, there is errors:
    operator: deepEqual
    expected: |-
    { '@@redux-saga/IO': true, CALL: { context: null, fn: [Function: getToken], 
    args: [] } }
    actual: |-
    undefined

And other 2 are the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. Other users shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand what you are asking. :-)

Comment: @Roland Weber, ohh, sorry, I edited :)

Comment: I guess the error try to say `Api.token.getToken` is undefined, it mean it's missing some import or at runtime some config is undefined.